# How to return a pointer to a unique_ptr wrapped pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

How can I create a pointer to a pointer that is wrapped inside a unique_ptr? In other words, is there a sound way to write this function:

```
int **getIterator(std::unique_ptr<int>& p)
{
     /* error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand */
     return &p.get();
}
```

Comment: No; as given, the function cannot be implemented reasonably. Can you shed some light into why you need it?

Comment: You're trying to break encapsulation by diving into implementation of `unique_ptr`. What's the idea?

Comment: Answer: You don't. What you propose makes no sense and shouldn't be done.

Comment: `unique_ptr` will delete the old pointer (if necessary) when assigned a new one. By doing this, you would break that behaviour.

Comment: I want to return a pointer to use as an iterator with an interface that expects iterators. I want to pass  `algo(getIterator(X), getIterator(X)+1)` so that single items look like collections. But I also want them to self-destruct.

Comment: @perreal why not just call `algo(p.get(), p.get() + 1)`?

Comment: @perreal: It sounds like you want `algo(p.get(), p.get()+1)`, using a pointer to the object, not a pointer to a pointer. Unless your algorithm expects an extra level of indirection for some reason, in which case you'll need a separate variable to temporarily hold a copy of the pointer (or a less insane algorithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to return a pointer to use as an iterator with an interface that expects iterators. I want to pass algo(getIterator(X), getIterator(X)+1) so that single items look like collections.

You are using `std::unique_ptr<int>`. If I understand your problem correctly, you are trying to do something, that is not necessary in this case: if you want to iterate through `int`s, you need `int*` (pointer to object), not `int**` (pointer to pointer).

Use this:

```
int* getIterator(std::unique_ptr<int>& p)
{
     return p.get();
}
```

Then, you can do what you wanted:

```
algo(getIterator(X), getIterator(X) + 1);
```

I expect `algo` being defined similar to this:

```
template <class Iter>
Result_type algo(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
  //algorithm
}
```

If you do something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p = /* initialize */;
algo(getIterator(p), getIterator(p) + 1);
```

You will receive two parameters of type `int*`, that can be safely moved forward/backward and dereferenced to get current object's value.